# How does one get the balance of an ETH address on Arbitrum or other L2's using eth-cli commands?

Tags: polygon, layer-2, arbitrum, eth-cli

Using eth-cli how do I access the balance of an address on L2's such as Arbitrum, Polygon, etc....